# Kill a running process using Flask RESTful API in Python

Tags: python, rest, api, flask-restful

I'm building a RESTful API in Python using Flask where I'm trying to get all running processes of the server and kill a process using it's process id. I've managed to get all processes but I'm having difficulties finding a way to kill a process.

If anyone could help with code for killing the process, it would be much appreciated.

You can find my code here (There's more in another file but it has nothing to do with killing the process):

```
from flask import Flask, json, jsonify, request, make_response
from flask_restful import Resource, abort, Api, reqparse
import psutil
from modules import Process, Disk

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


class Processes(Resource):
    def get(self):
        list = []
        plist = psutil.process_iter()
        for proc in plist:
            process = psutil.Process(proc.pid)
            naam = process.name()
            processid = proc.pid

            proc = Process(naam, processid)

            list.append(proc.serialize())
        return jsonify(list)

    def post(self, pid):
        process = psutil.Process(pid)
        process.kill()
        return "Process terminated!",200


api.add_resource(Processes, '/processes')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(Debug=True)
```

Comment: Do you see an error when you run this? Could you please attach an error trace?
The killing of a process problem you are describing seems unrelated to flask restplus or flask. Try isolating the code to do that and try solving it separately.